# On page reload: Redirect all routes to '/'

Tags: vue-router

When users reload a page (that is not the `/` route) they should be redirected to `/`. I've tried this but that ends up in an infinite loop:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (from.path === '/' && to.path !== '/' && store.state.loggedIn) { 
        next()
    } else {
        next('/')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from path and to path together are causing the infinite loop

basically do this

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (!store.state.loggedIn && to.path !== '/') { 
        next('/')
    }
})
```